# float of string object not considered a positive value - python

Tags: python, list

So I have this list of string objects - collist5:

```py
['1367.36', '-9.99', '-1462', '943.48', '1162.76', '943.48', '-9.15', '0.27', '-100', '1184.68']
```

I am trying to remove all the positive values from it using this:

```
x = 0
for object in collist5 :
    if float(object) > 0 :
        collist5.pop(x)
        x = x + 1
    else:
        x = x + 1
```

The code removes all of the positive values except for one - '1162.76'

```
['-9.99', '-1462', '1162.76', '-9.15', '-100']
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been struggling with this for way too long!

Comment: Sorry guys my brain is fried I have to look at this again in the morning. the problem is I have several other lists, collist2, collist4, etc... that I am trying to remove the same indexed object from. So for example if object # 5 in collist5 is positive I want it to also remove object # 5 from collist2 and collist4. none of these solutions have worked so far for that.

Comment: Good holy and righteous yet unforgiving god. After roughly seven hours of work I think I got it. List comprehension.  I used: output = [(x, y, z) for x,y,z in zip(collist5,collist4,collist2) if float(x) < 0] to create a list of tuples and then I made new lists from the list of tuples. This lets me delete the corresponding index in each list when a positive number is found.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are removing items from the list during iteration on it, `pop()` shifts the remaining items to close the gap but the index remain the same. You should iterate over a copy of the list and remove from the original. You can also use `remove(object)` instead of `pop()`, that way you don't need to keep the index

```
for num in collist5[:]:
    if float(num) > 0:
        collist5.remove(num)

print(collist5) # ['-9.99', '-1462', '-9.15', '-100']
```

As a side note, don't use `object` as a variable name, it's a built-in class.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use list comprehension:

```py
collist5 = ['1367.36', '-9.99', '-1462', '943.48', '1162.76', '943.48', '-9.15', '0.27', '-100', '1184.68']
output = [x for x in collist5 if float(x) <= 0]
print(output) # ['-9.99', '-1462', '-9.15', '-100']
```

Answer (score 1):

You start at x=0 and you are popping the values ​​in the array.

```
collist5 = ['1367.36', '-9.99', '-1462', '943.48', '1162.76', '943.48', '-9.15', '0.27', '-100', '1184.68']
```

If x=0 is greater than 0, after poping from the array, you will want to check index 1, -9.99 .

But after collist5.pop(0) ,

```
collist5 = ['-9.99', '-1462', '943.48', '1162.76', '943.48', '-9.15', '0.27', '-100', '1184.68']
```

the index of -9.99 will be 0 instead of 1. you get an index you can't check.

So if you want to solve this, just reverse it.

```
    x = len(collist5)
    for object in collist5 :
        if float(object) > 0 :
            collist5.pop(x)
        x -= 1
```

or

```
collist5 = [x for x in collist5 if float(x) <= 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehension is the best way:

```
out_list=[x for x in collist5 if float(x)<0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any type conversion, just check if the string representation of the float value startswith `-` inside a List-Comprehension:

```py
>>> [item for item in collist5 if item.startswith('-')]

Out[4]: ['-9.99', '-1462', '-9.15', '-100']
```